# Python 3.4 - Looping under a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm pretty new to Python and would like your advise on this. I want to create an array of square number (i.e., 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, etc.)

Here is my current code:

```
def near(limit):
    for element in limit:
        answer = 0
        rounding1 = math.ceil(element ** 0.5)
        rounding2 = math.floor(element ** 0.5)
        result1 = rounding1 ** 2
        result2 = rounding2 ** 2
        lambda1 = abs(result1 - element)
        lambda2 = abs(result2 - element)
        if lambda1 < lambda2:
            answer = result1
        else:
            answer = result2
            return answer

listing = list(range(1,2000)) 
nearing = near(listing)
```

But from this code, I am still unable to produce an array/list of squared numbers. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To create a list of square numbers you can do `[x*x for x in range(limit)]`

Comment: in this code, the return statement will exit the function on the first iteration, you should build a list inside the function, or use the keyword `yield` instead (and move it outside the `else` block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

**1. Using Map concept**

As you are new to python, please go through Map, Filter and Reduce concepts. They provide the simplest one line solutions to certain kinds of problems.

Now, let's assume that you are looking for a straight list of squares for a given input list i.e.

input = [1, 2, 3, 4....]
output = [1, 4, 9, 16....]

You can simply do this by adding the following line to your code

> mySquaresList = list(map(lambda x : x**2, range(1, 2000)))

**2. Your approach**

I am guessing from the way you wrote your program, you are probably looking for squares of input list [34.5, 45.6, 48.......] and expecting an output of [1156.0, 2025.0, 2304.0.......]

Your code is wonderful, but there are few bugs in your code which are very minor.

1. Initialise an **empty list**, before your for loop to store all your squares in each iteration.
2. The **math.ceiling(yourNumber)** itself gives a smallest integer value, so there is no requirement for math.ceiling(yourNumber ** 0.5) which gives you a square root of given normal number, similarly **math.floor(yourNumber)** gives the largest integer value and your logic gives you are direct square root of given number, which is where your logic is mostly going wrong.
3. You are returning your **answer** which is wrong, your program control comes out of the loop immediately after solving first element. And other thing associated with your program is, you placed your return statement in the else part of if condition which is part of a for loop, which is also a mistake. So, remove your return answer statement and add **yourList.append(answer)** out side of if condition within your for loop.
4. Place your return after your for loop and **return yourList**, instead of answer. So, after the completion of computing your logic this program returns a list of squares.

Final code looks like this

```
def near(limit):

    mySquares = list()

    for element in limit:

        answer = 0

        rounding1 = math.ceil(element)
        rounding2 = math.floor(element)

        result1 = rounding1 ** 2
        result2 = rounding2 ** 2

        lambda1 = abs(result1 - element)
        lambda2 = abs(result2 - element)

        if lambda1 < lambda2:
            answer = result1
        else:
            answer = result2

        mySquares.append(answer)

    return mySquares


listing = [34.5, 45.6, 48]
nearing = near(listing)
```

You can remove your answer = 0 line, which is not necessary.

Hope this is what you are looking for. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that on your first loop your return an Item (answer) so your `near` function calculates only first item in `limit` argument and the rest is ignored

you can create a temp_list and then simply (outside for loop) return the temp list

```
def near(limit):
    temp_list = []
    for element in limit:
        ...
        # instead of return write
        temp_list.append(element)

    return temp_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
def near(limit):

    squares = []
    for element in limit:
        squares.append(element*element)

    return squares


listing = list(range(0,10))
nearing = near(listing)

print(nearing)
```

Gives back:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/michael/PycharmProjects/atm-zeiterfassung/test.py
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

HTH?